# Реализация jwt Asp.net Core. Web Api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, oauth, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

Имеется задача реализовать сервер использую Asp.Net Core. Web Api 2. Реализовал авторизацию с jwt токенам по гайдам подобным этому: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1217608/ASP-NET-Core-Identity-Supporting-JWT-Token-for-use

Возник вопрос: как реализовать для разных клиентов свой secretkey?
И каковы недостатки такой реализацию по сравнению с oauth2?

startup.cs:

```
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => { options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")); });

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                cfg.SaveToken = true;
                cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["JwtOptions:Issuer"],

                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["JwtOptions:Audience"],

                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JwtOptions:Key"])),

                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero 
                };
            });

        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

Генерация токена:

```
    private string GenerateJwtToken(ApplicationUser user, string role)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Email),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
            new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType, role)
        };

        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["JwtOptions:Key"]));
        var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        var expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(Convert.ToDouble(_configuration["JwtOptions:ExpireDays"]));

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: _configuration["JwtOptions:Issuer"],
            audience: _configuration["JwtOptions:Audience"],
            claims: claims,
            notBefore: DateTime.UtcNow,
            expires: expires,
            signingCredentials: creds
        );

        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
    }
```